# how to find my generated ssh key

Tags: ssh

I am trying to setup my ssh keys to be used for Bitbucket authentication (Mac, OS X 10.9.3).

1. I generated the keys using $ ssh-keygen
2. I got the return "Generating public/private rsa key pair"
3. I subsequently entered and re-entered the passphrase as prompted to do
4. I got the return that "Your identification has been saved in myPassPhrase.
   Your public key has been saved in myPassPhrase.pub.

When I now run ls -a ~/.ssh no keys show in the list...

Anyone have any idea where to find my keys now?

Thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

Check in file "myPassPhrase.pub"?

Comment: found my keys, I thought they would be store by default in ~/.ssh, but not so, saved plainly in my user directory. Seems I have to copy them over manually.